# Looking for a ~2000s cartoon with a blonde guy in his teens investigating anomalies where he hunts/catches aliens/monsters

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon

If I remember correctly he was an agent of some sort of organization, might have had companions, but not too sure about them.

It's not *Huntik* or *Ben 10*.

Comment: Ah, so "teens" probably eliminates the [Roswell Conspiracies](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/RoswellConspiraciesAliensMythsAndLegends).

Comment: Do you remember whether he was still in high school? College? Homeschooled? Dropout? Did he use magic? Technology? Sheer determination?

Comment: Johny Quest?  Or maybe Johny Test? What sort of animation we are talking about? Animesque, cartoonish...

Answer (score 4):

Could it have been [The Secret Saturdays](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1291662/)? Your list of which shows it *wasn't* leads me to believe you were considering Cartoon Network shows, and this popped into mind.
Intro:

Description:

> From their hidden base, heroic scientists Doc, Drew and Zak Saturday work with a network of cryptozoologists committed to protecting mankind against hidden horrors most people don't even know exist.

IIRC, most episodes involve some reports of strange creatures ("cryptids") that this family then proceed to track down and capture.

Answer (score 3):

Just spent an hour looking for this, it's [*Dex Hamilton: Alien Entomologist*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1308744/).

Summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dex_Hamilton:_Alien_Entomologist):

> It is the year 3000. Dex Hamilton, a young entomologist and wildlife explorer is called into action when alien insects crawling through the galaxy create a dangerous rift between man and nature. Accompanied by his team of scientists, Zap Monogan, Jenny 10 and Tung "the fantastic frog boy", Dex sets out to observe and capture these strange specimens.
>
> Meanwhile, a villain is genetically modifying super bugs to destroy all worlds.

Comment: Welcome. Are you the person who asked the question above? Or are you someone else who was also looking for the cartoon?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the question?  For one thing it looks like Dex isn't blonde?

Comment: @Clockwork I am someone else who was looking for the same cartoon, so I stubled across this forum and was like "that is exactly the show Im thinking about!" So I kept looking for it and eventually found it, so I figured Id share it here

Comment: @DavidW Dex is blond in the 2d version of the cartoon. It has apparently gotten a remake later where its a different animation style, and Dexs hair looks a bit darker, but Id still call it blond. Other than that Dex hamilton perfectly matches the plot line of traveling around capturing aliens, the age and companion stuff also fits

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like *[Martin Mystery (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Mystery)*.

[image: A poster of Martin Mystery, with the title written in French in the upper left corner. 4 recurring characters can be seen on it, 3 of which are the main protagonists.]

- The main character, Martin Mystery, is a 16-year-old blond haired guy. He's always seen wearing his typical shirt with flame pattern, and a special watch with which he can pull out gadgets to help in his mission (such as devices to analyse substances, or weapons). He's always followed by his two associates.
- On the right, Diana Lombard, Martin's stepsister, is a 16-year-old brown haired girl always seen wearing a pink/purple top. She attends the same school as Martin.
- On the left is Java the Caveman, a caveman that is always seen wearing a yellow shirt. Because he's a caveman, he looks very tough. Martin freed him from a prison at his job, and since then he's been working with them.
- The tiny green alien hovering in the back is Billy, the secretary of the organisation for which they work.

They work as a team, as part of an organisation called *"The Center"*. Their purpose is to investigate paranormal activities and solve them, which involves detective work, and then capturing whoever (or whatever) was causing the paranormal phenomena. It's similar to Scooby-Doo, except that it's always real monsters and aliens in this cartoon.